# Runtime error with array and struct with swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, runtime-error

I am new to Swift and I am stuck on an error that must be stupid!!! Here is the code

```
import Foundation

struct Serie {
    var nomeEsercizio = ""
    var ripetizioni=0
    var chili=0.0
    var recupero=0
}

struct Superserie {
    var elementi: [Serie] = []
}

struct Scheda {
    var elementi: [Superserie] = []
}

class Schede {
    var elementi: [Scheda] = []
    func isEmpty() -> Bool {
        return elementi.isEmpty
    }
}

class GestoreDiSchede {
    static var schedeLocali = Schede()
    static var username = "empty"

class func initializeUserDefaults () {
        var superserieTemp = Superserie()
        var scheda = Scheda()
        let schede = Schede()

        superserieTemp.elementi.append(Serie(nomeEsercizio: "Spinte manubri", ripetizioni: 10, chili: 10, recupero: 0))     //....more code
```

I cannot post the screenshot of the debugger but here the values of the items of the variable "elementi" inside the struct "superserieTemp" are assigned RANDOMLY!!!!! why?
I have tried everything but I am not able to get the code working, please help :(

EDIT <-----------
After some hours I found out that the error occurs because I am not able to properly initialise a struct of array of struct. How can I do it? 
If I do the following way, then when I try to append an item in the array inside the bigger struct, I get this error "variable 'a' passed by reference before begin initialised". The 'a' variable refers to the code below.

```
struct Inside {
    var something: String
    var somethingElse: Int
}
struct Outside {
    var array: [Inside]
    init(){
        self.array = []
    }
}
//then the error is given in the following lines (which are placed inside a method of another class)
var a: Outside
a.array.append.(Inside("aaaa",1111))
```

Where is the issue?

EDIT EDIT <-----------
this it the right (not compiling) code, I had written the previous one directly in stack overflow

```
struct Inside {
    var something: String
    var somethingElse: Int
}
struct Outside {
    var array: [Inside]
    init(){
        self.array = []
    }
}
//then the error is given in the following lines (which are placed inside a method of another class)
        var a: Outside
        a.array.append(Inside(something: "aaaa",somethingElse: 1111))
```

Comment: When encountering a bug and you don't know how to fix it, remove as much code as possible while still getting the bug. This way you can find out where the bug really occurs. This is called [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example)

Comment: I have done what you have said and I have written another post but I can post it because 90 minutes are not passed. The problem is that I am not able to initialise a struct containing an Array of struct. How can I do it the right way?

Comment: Don't ask another question, edit this one!

Comment: It is a good idea. I will do just now. Please hold on :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code you aren't initializing the variable `a` but in Swift every value has to be initialized before useable. When changing the last two lines to this:

```
var a = Outside()
a.array.append(Inside(something: "aaaa", somethingElse: 1111))
```

it works for me just fine (Swift 2.0)

Or you can remove the custom initializer which prevented the default initializer from being generated, then it looks like this:

```
struct Inside {
    var something: String
    var somethingElse: Int
}

struct Outside {
    var array: [Inside]
}

let a = Outside(array: [Inside(something: "aaaa", somethingElse: 1111)])
```

Comment: I will try immediately.

Comment: In the original code I have got a class containing an Array of struct containing an Array of struct containing an Array of struct. I was afraid that your suggestion wouldn't have worked in this complicated case but it did!
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

A few errors with your code: (1) `a` is not initialized. You just declared it being of type `Outside`. (2) You have an extra dot after append. (3) You need parameter labels with the default initializer for `Inside`.

```
struct Inside {
    var something: String
    var somethingElse: Int
}

struct Outside {
    var array = [Inside]() // Don't need to initialize array in your init call
}

var a = Outside()
a.array.append(Inside(something: "aaaa",somethingElse: 1111))
```